# How should I be setting my Attribute Pointers for my text?

Tags: c++, opengl

I've defined a block of vertex data like so:

```
struct vertex {
    float x, y, u, v;
};

struct vertex_group {
    vertex tl, bl, br, tr;
    glm::vec4 color;

    vertex_group(float x, float y, float width, float height, glm::vec4 c) {
        tl.x = x;           tl.y = y + height;  tl.u = 0; tl.v = 0;
        bl.x = x;           bl.y = y;           bl.u = 0; bl.v = 1;
        br.x = x + width;   br.y = y;           br.u = 1; br.v = 1;
        tr.x = x + width;   tr.y = y + height;  tr.u = 1; tr.v = 0;
        color = c;
    }

    vertex_group(positioned_letter const& l) :
    vertex_group(l.x, l.y, l.width, l.height, l.l.color) {
    }

    const float * data() const {
        return &tl.x;
    }
};
```

The attribute pointers are set like this:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), nullptr);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)(4 * 4 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
```

And the draw code is invoked like so:

```
vertex_group vertices(l);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g.texture);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, objects.rect_buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices.data(), GL_STREAM_DRAW);
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
```

The basic idea is that all four vertices of the quad should all be using the same data for color, even as they require different values for position and texture data. However, when I set the color to red (1,0,0,1), the results on screen are.... not quite right.

[image: Font rendered incorrectly]

Just for reference sake, if the ***only** changes I make are to the first two sections of code, to the following:

```
struct vertex {
    float x, y, u, v;
};

struct vertex_group {
    vertex tl;
    glm::vec4 color1;
    vertex bl;
    glm::vec4 color2;
    vertex br;
    glm::vec4 color3;
    vertex tr;
    glm::vec4 color4;

    vertex_group(float x, float y, float width, float height, glm::vec4 c) {
        tl.x = x;           tl.y = y + height;  tl.u = 0; tl.v = 0;
        bl.x = x;           bl.y = y;           bl.u = 0; bl.v = 1;
        br.x = x + width;   br.y = y;           br.u = 1; br.v = 1;
        tr.x = x + width;   tr.y = y + height;  tr.u = 1; tr.v = 0;
        color1 = color2 = color3 = color4 = c;
    }

    vertex_group(positioned_letter const& l) :
    vertex_group(l.x, l.y, l.width, l.height, l.l.color) {
    }

    const float * data() const {
        return &tl.x;
    }
};
```

(other part)

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), nullptr);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(4 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
```

It renders correctly:

[image: Font Renders Correctly]

So in a nutshell, my question is: I'd like to structure my data (and render with it) like `xyuvxyuvxyuvxyuvrgba` but the only way I can get it to work is by doing `xyuvrgbaxyuvrgbaxyuvrgbaxyuvrgba`. How do I set my pointers/call the draw function so that I can use the first method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that. But you can achieve this layout using instanced rendering:

```
xyuvxyuvxyuvxyuv              // <- only once
whrgbawhrgbawhrgbawhrgba...   // <- repeated per glyph
```

where w and h are the sizes of each quad **that are to be applied in the vertex shader**.

Here I split it in two buffers, but you can technically load it all into one buffer. Also I use the OpenGL 4.5 bindless API here because I think that it is easier to use. If you don't have it yet then you can change it to use the older calls accordingly.

```
float quad[] = {
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 0,
    1, 0, 1, 1,
};

struct Instance {
    vec2 size;
    // TODO: add index of the glyph you want to render
    vec4 color;
};

Instance inst[] = { ... };
int ninst = sizeof(inst)/sizeof(inst[0]);

GLuint quad_buf = ... create buffer from quad[] ...;
GLuint inst_buf = ... create buffer from inst[] ...;

GLuint vao;
glCreateVertexArrays(1, &vao);

glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(vao, 0);
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vao, 0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);
glVertexArrayAttribBinding(vao, 0, 0); // from 0th buffer

glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(vao, 1);
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vao, 1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, offsetof(Instance, size));
glVertexArrayAttribBinding(vao, 1, 1); // from 1st buffer

glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(vao, 2);
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vao, 2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, offsetof(Instance, color));
glVertexArrayAttribBinding(vao, 2, 1); // from 1st buffer

glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, 0, quad_buf, 0, sizeof(float)*4); // 0th buffer is the quad
glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, 1, inst_buf, 0, sizeof(Instance)); // 1th buffer for instances
glVertexArrayBindingDivisor(vao, 1, 1); // 1st buffer advances once per instance

// to draw:
glBindTexture(...);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4, ninst);
```

Comment: I use two testing computers, one of which is strictly limited to OpenGL 4.3, so I can't use the DSA api. I like your solution though; I'll see how it works for me.